# JSSOR Slider - Download package does not have source for x-swing slider

Tags: jquery, jssor

While I was searching Google for JQuery Sliders, I came across this site:
http://www.jssor.com/

I did the download, but "x-swing" slider is not found (and also some other, which comes under "Demo Slideshows") in the download.
Its demo url is : http://www.jssor.com/demos/x-swing.html

Can anybody let me know where I could get this source?

Answer (score 1):

This page demonstrates slideshow effects 'swing'.

You can get hundreds of slideshow transition code here http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html